# Command "generate:module" is not a valid command name

Tags: console

I have this problem when I run command `drupal generate:module`. I don't know why, despite everything I did was suggested on [the documentation for Drupal Console](https://www.drupal.org/node/2361869).

I don't see all the possible commands, when I run `drupal list`.

```
Available commands:
  about                      Displays basic information about Drupal Console project
  chain                      Chain command execution
  check                      System requirement checker
  exec                       Execute an external command.
  help                       Displays help for a command
  init                       Copy configuration files.
  list                       Lists all available commands
 debug
  debug:chain (dch)          List available chain files.
  debug:settings (dse)       List user Drupal Console settings.
  debug:site (dsi)           List all known local and remote sites.
 develop
  develop:contribute         Download Drupal + Drupal Console to contribute.
 generate
  generate:site:alias (gsa)  Generates a site alias.
 quick
  quick:start                Download, install and serve a new Drupal project
 settings
  settings:set               Change a specific setting value in DrupalConsole config file
 site
  site:new                   Download a new Drupal project
```

Comment: Console can't connect to your Drupal site. You probably don't have database credentials set up correctly, or you're running the command outside of the site root

Comment: yeah probably , because when i run this command again "drupal list" it shows me the possible command above , and also this error ' [ERROR] The specified database connection is not defined: default   ' , i am using docker  and a mysql image , can docker causes this problem?

Comment: Sounds likely yeah

Comment: i  have already connected to my database and all data showing up on the site , so i think there is some other problem not with the database connection

Comment: From where you are executing the command? From outside the container? Or from inside the container as in `docker exec -it MY-CONTAINER drupal generate:module`?

Comment: the container of what? , i have 4 i run docker psand it gives me ' contaier runing : nginx-proxy ,drupal8-app_web_1,drupal8-app_mysql_1,drupal8-app_gulp_1

Comment: Probably `drupal8-app_web_1`

Comment: should i run this "docker exec -it drupal8-app_web_1 vendor/bin/drupal generate:module" or this : "docker exec -it drupal8-app_web_1 drupal generate:module"

Comment: It would be best if you get into the container and there run the command instead of shove it directly through the stdin. Something like `docker exec -it drupal8-app_web_1 bash` and them got to your Drupal root and `vendor/bin/drupal generate:module`. Not related but should make your dockerized Drupal life easier https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal

Comment: Plus, you can add shortcuts with a Makefile or .ahoy.yml file so you can simplify it down to `make console ...args` or `ahoy console ...args`.

Comment: @Kevin – Or DDEV at best. Then it's just `ddev drupal generate:module`.

Comment: @d70rr3s when i run this command " docker exec -it drupal8-app_web_1 drupal generate:module" it shows me this error " [ERROR] Class Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel does not exist."

Comment: @lovecoding as I mentioned this could occur since your entrypoint to that container may not be set at your Drupal root. It's best to enter into the container, locate your Drupal root and execute there the command. Also your database error is that the connection details are wrong, if you are using different container for the DB you should use its name or service label not its IP address. Furthermost check environment suggestions from comments above.

Comment: @d70rr3s when i run "root@f57ec41a2698:/var/www/html# vendor/bin/drupal generate:module" bash: vendor/bin/drupal: No such file or directory ,when i LS the file vendor i cna't find bin folder ?

Comment: @d70rr3s this is my "ls" in rooot inside the container ==> root@f57ec41a2698:/var/www/html# ls
INSTALL.txt  LICENSE.txt  README.txt  autoload.php  composer.json  composer.lock  core  example.gitignore  index.php  libraries  modules  profiles  robots.txt  sites  themes  update.php  vendor  web.config

Comment: Seems to me you need to execute composer install or you don't have drupal/console as requirement see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem this works 100 %  :

1. open the shell and  `cd to projectFolder`
2. run this command :

```
   composer require drupal/console:~1.0 --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
```

3. then run this command :

```
   composer update drupal/console --with-dependencies
```

4. run `drupal list` command again, and you'll find the list of all commands.

   **! this steps must be repeated with each project.**

Comment: it generate some list but not all of them , and throws this error " [ERROR] The specified database connection is not defined: default  " , and i am using docker ,so i should get into web container ? , also when i run this command " docker exec -it drupal8-app_web_1 drupal generate:module" it shows me this error " [ERROR] Class Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel does not exist."

Comment: when i run compose require ............ it gives me this =====> Nothing to install or update
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead................

Comment: Try `--with-all-dependencies` instead of `--with-dependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was resolved when I deleted extra blank composer.json file present inside "web" directory. Not sure how it got created but the issue got resolved when I deleted non-required composer.json

**Folder Structure with Issue**
/path/to/site/dev

config/
vendor/
web/
composer.json
composer.lock
web/composer.json

**Proposed fix**
/path/to/site/dev

config/
web/
vendor/
composer.json
composer.lock

I got answer from below link, reposting if it helps someone

https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/issues/3925